# Invoking Watson speech-to-text from Java through a corporate proxy

Tags: ibm-watson

I am using the Watson Java SDK from github (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) to run a test of the speech-to-text service. I am running an example from my workplace, which has a firewall and an http proxy set up.

The test fails because the remote server cannot be reached. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: stream.watsonplatform.net
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:182)
    at com.costaisa.app.api.test.ibm.watson.TestIBMWatson.testSpeechToText(TestIBMWatson.java:76)
    at com.costaisa.app.api.test.ibm.watson.TestIBMWatson.main(TestIBMWatson.java:37)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: stream.watsonplatform.net
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:179)
    ... 2 more
```

It seems to me that okhttp3 supports HTTP proxies but not through environment variables or system properties.

Am I missing something? Is it at all possible to invoke the Watson speech-to-text service from Java through a proxy?

---

**EDIT**

I'm no longer working with Watson (not even the same job!), but it became apparent that what I wanted to do was not possible with the then current implementation. A comment to this question (not an answer) provided the actual answer: you cannot do it without changing the implementation. I'd vote that as an answer, but alas it's only a comment. I hope this is useful for other people looking for an answer.

Comment: Hey Juanjo, you can setup the service url to point to your proxy. We don't expose the HTTPClient from okHttp so you won't be able to use okhttp for this

Comment: Thanks for replying. And how would I do such a thing? I can't find any reference to that in the github repo.

And when you mention "proxy", do you mean an http proxy? That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: I can merge a pull request if you find a way cleaver way of having this functionality without exposing the implementation too much

Comment: @GermanAttanasio this is the proxy setting: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#proxy-java.net.Proxy- - perhaps WatsonService.java could get a setProxy method, or alternatively just let the user provide their own OkhttpClient/Builder

Comment: I know about the proxy. I just didn't want to expose that we were using okhttp for HTTP because If we decide to change the underlying dependency we will break all the users sending us an OkHttpCLient instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Juanjo** this is what you can do to pass the request through corporate proxy.

Create a class that extends from TextToSpeech (as [ExtendedTextToSpeech that I wrote for me.](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/gauravwasan/dByoo)).
Then change the DemoServlet that comes with the watson sample as below

```
             TextToSpeech textService = new com.ibm.cloudoe.samples.ExtendedTextToSpeech();
             textService.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
             String voice = req.getParameter("voice");
             String text = req.getParameter("text");
             String format = "audio/ogg; codecs=opus";
             in = textService.synthesize(text, new Voice(voice, null, null), format);
```

If you get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, then

- login to stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1 with your username/password received from your watson account's text-to-speech service
- Click on the lock sign in the browser's address bar and export the certificate.
- Follow the steps here http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm using SpeechToText, not TextToSpeech.
In any case, I don't have any servlet deployed anywhere: I'm consuming the SpeechToText service, and it fails because my code cannot reach the stream.watsonplatform.net host. Hence my question: how can I do that via a corporate proxy.

Comment: Hi @JuanjoAparicioJara I looked at the SpeechToText class, you will need to create your class ExtendedSpeechToText thats extends com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText (as I created ExtendedTextToSpeech). Your class should have the same code as in ExtendedTextToSpeech where you create the OkHttpClient client that has the proxy configuration.  Then in your client  where you instantiate SpeechToText, use 'SpeechToTect service = new ExtendedSpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");
Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, indeed. But that means that you cannot specify the proxy configuration to the service, you have to partially reimplement the connection.

Thanks to all for your help.